# Titanium simple xhr POST of binary won't work

Tags: xmlhttprequest, titanium

I am trying to do this curl post in Titanium but I keep getting a 400 error. 
I have tried passing the data as a Javascript object. I tried also changing the header.
Maybe I haven't hit the right combination of things.
Please help.

```
curl 'https://ortc-mobilepush.realtime.co/mp/publish' --data-binary '{"applicationKey": "[INSERT_YOUR_APP_KEY]","privateKey": "[INSERT_YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY]",
        "channel" : "NewArticles", 
        "message" : "We have new articles for you",
        "payload" : "{ \"sound\" : \"default\", \"badge\" : \"2\" }" }'   


var url = 'https://ortc-mobilepush.realtime.co/mp/publish';
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
 // function called when the response data is available
 onload : function(e) {
     Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
     alert('success');
 },
 // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
 onerror : function(e) {
     Ti.API.debug(e);
     //alert('error');
 },
 timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
});

client.open("POST", url);
client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
// Send the request.
var text = '{"applicationKey": "[App Key]","privateKey": "[Private key]", "channel" :   "GlobalChanell", "message" : "test", "payload" : "{ \"sound\" : \"default\", \"badge\" : \"32\" }" }';
client.send(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

recently I also faced same problem in one of my client application...
so i should give solution for that..

may be there is a problem of server url...so you can try to change that url and replace it with something below...

https://exampleserver.com/mp/publish

then set Content-Type to application/json
and create json object like below....

```
var text = {
    applicationKey : [key],
    privateKey : [p_key],
    etc....
}
```

then pass it like....

client.send(JSON.stringify(text));